# How do I change my AWS CLI drive from H to C

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have AWS CLI V2 installed on my company laptop which is on Windows 10 Enterprise.

The AWSCLI is located at `C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2`

When I enter `aws configure` it is saving my credentials in `H:\` drive which is a network drive and I'm facing latency issues.

How do I move my `.aws` to `C:\` drive to avoid latency?

Answer (score 2):

According to the AWS documentation on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/credref/latest/refdocs/file-location.html#file-location-config the default location of the `.aws` directory is the home folder of the user.

You can override the exact location of the `config` and `credentials` files (which the `aws configure` call is writing) using the environment variables `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` and `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE`, respectively.

Quote from the AWS documentation:

> You can move the config file and the credentials file or even rename them as long as you tell the SDKs and tools how to find the information.
>
> To do this, set the following environment variables to point to the files containing the configuration or credentials information, according to the rules of your operating system:
>
> Config file – AWS_CONFIG_FILE
>
> Credentials file – AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE